# Not reaching part of code

Tags: python

My piece of code below is not reaching the intended point.

```
print("Welcome to the Stockroom\n")    
print("The following products need new stock:\n")
f = open("lowstock","r")
print(f.read())
choice = input("\nTo update the stock levels of the above products, type 1. To cancel, enter anything else.")
if choice == '1':
    with open('stockcontrol.csv',newline='') as f:
        for line in f:
            data = line.split(",")
            productcode = int(data[0])
            target = int(data[2])
            stocklevel = int(data[1])
            if stocklevel <= 5:
                target = str(target)
                import sys
                import csv
                data=[]
               # code = code
                newval= target
                newtlevel = "0"
                f=open("stockcontrol.csv")
                reader=csv.DictReader(f,fieldnames=['code','level', 'target', 'distancefromtarget'])
                for line in reader:
                    line['level']= newval
                    line['distancefromtarget']= newtlevel
                    data.append('%s,%s,%s,%s'%(line['code'],line['level'],line['target'],line['distancefromtarget']))
                    f.close()
                    f=open("stockcontrol.csv","w")
                    f.write("\n".join(data))
                    f.close()
                    print("The stock levels were updated successfully")
else:
    print("Goodbye")
```

If 1 is inputted on the choice input, the program just terminates - any ideas why it is not replacing the string in the csv etc? What is stopping it from reaching this stage?

Comment: What Python version? `input()` is different on Py2 and Py3, so the input may be interpreted as integer. Try `if str(choice) == "1": ...`

Comment: The same happens @linusg - I am on Python 3.4.2

Comment: So it prints out `Goodbye`? That cannot be...

Comment: No, it prints nothing, just terminates @linusg

Comment: Does it not even print "Goodbye"? With cutting the complete logic your code works for me.

Comment: How do you execute your file?

Comment: If I remove speech marks around the 1, it then prints goodbye, instead of terminating or doing what it's supposed to and using the if statement @linusg

Comment: Just run by F5 in Idle @syntonym

Comment: What happens if you delete the "f.read()"? It might be that your file is read in that step and then later in `for line in f` you already read the file to the end, so you can't read the file again. Try something like `lines = f.readlines()` and only read your file once.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114153/discussion-between-nathan-shoesmith-and-syntonym).

Comment: This is very nested...you might consider some print debugging. Print at least one thing in each level of nesting and see which level you aren't triggering

Comment: It's going straight to 'Goodbye' @Lost

Comment: There are a few odd things in your code. For one, importing stuff mid-function gets confusing; put imports at the top instead. You're redefining `f` by writing `with open('stockcontrol.csv',newline='') as f:` and then `f=open("stockcontrol.csv")` later on (also, the file is already open). To avoid excessive nesting, you could write a `csv_to_list` function and a `list_to_csv` function. The first would take a file name as input, maybe the field names as well, and return a list of lists/rows. The 2nd could take a list of lists/rows as input and write the data to a csv file.

Comment: Nathan, not originally, you stated that before you changed to 1 being an int instead of the original string "1" that it did nothing. This tells me it probably was running into your main loop but didn't make it far enough to do any of the prints or edits. Swap back to the string, add some debug lines to the loops and see if you can find where it's failing to proceed. Several of your inner loops would have no obvious output as currently written so may be executing without you knowing

Comment: @Lost - I have swapped back to before, the debug lines show it terminating once it gets to 'if stocklevel <= 5:'

Comment: @NathanShoesmith Then your code is determining your input just fine. Make sure that you are grabbing the correct data for stocklevel and change it accordingly

Comment: @NathanShoesmith I'm not sure if you mean it stops at the if check or if it gets into that nest but doesn't go to the next one. If it doesn't pass the if check then have it print out your "stocklevel" variable and see what it shows. If it gets into the IF loop but doesn't move on to the for loop then I'd rework your logic to use a `with open() as csv_file:` type logic then put another print statement in to make sure your file is opening properly.

Comment: The code gets into the for loop, but breaks immediately at if stocklevel.... @Lost

Comment: @NathanShoesmith If you print(stocklevel) right before the if what value for stocklevel does it print? If you aren't triggering your if statement I'm inclined to agree with TheLazyScripter that there is an input data issue because that check is rather unambigious

Answer (score 1):

In Python 3, the `input` function always returns a string. So if the user enters `1`, `choice` will be `"1"`, not the integer `1` which you're testing for.

You seem to have edited the question to change things in the wrong direction, for reasons that are unclear to me. You either want `int(input())`, or you need to test against `"1"`. (There may be other additional issues, but this is the main one with the code as it appears at the moment.)